# Ошибка при подключении execution в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Не получается подключить библиотеку execution в Qt при подключении к новому пустому проекту выдаёт ошубку в хедере

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <execution>
```

и сразу после этого появляется ошибка:

```
/home/username/QtProjects/untitled/mainwindow.h:6: ошибка: In included file: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
```

при попытке скомпилировать пояляется несколько ошибок:

```
/usr/include/oneapi/tbb/profiling.h:229: ошибка: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
In file included from /usr/include/oneapi/tbb/detail/_small_object_pool.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/oneapi/tbb/detail/_task.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/oneapi/tbb/parallel_for.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:17,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/pstl/parallel_backend_tbb.h:20,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/pstl/parallel_backend.h:20,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/pstl/algorithm_impl.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/pstl/glue_execution_defs.h:50,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/execution:32,
                 from ../untitled/mainwindow.h:6,
                 from ../untitled/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/oneapi/tbb/profiling.h:229:15: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
  229 |     void emit() { }
      |               ^
```

```
/usr/include/oneapi/tbb/profiling.h:231: ошибка: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
/usr/include/oneapi/tbb/profiling.h:231:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
  231 |     static void emit(const std::string &) { }
      |                      ^~~~~
```

```
/usr/include/oneapi/tbb/profiling.h:231: ошибка: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/oneapi/tbb/profiling.h:231:22: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
  231 |     static void emit(const std::string &) { }
      |                     ~^~~~~
      |                      )
```

если перейти в файл на который указывает ошибка, то там вроде как всё нормально:

```
struct event {
    event(const std::string &) { }

    void emit() { }

    static void emit(const std::string &) { }
};
```

Пытался менять комплекты 5.15.2/6.4.0 ошибка повторяется. В .pro файле указал что нужно использовать C++17
`CONFIG += c++17`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В библиотеке Qt определен макрос `#define emit`. Это вызывает конфликты с другими библиотеками, где это слово используется в качестве переменной или имени функции.
(Есть и другие "скользкие" макросы, например: `signals`, `slots`...)
см. https://github.com/mburakov/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h#L80

Чтобы отключить этот макрос, нужно определить макрос `#define QT_NO_EMIT`, до включения первого заголовочного файла Qt, в каждой единице трансляции, где используются библиотеки, конфликтующие с `emit`.

Или можно установить его во всем проекте: `DEFINES+=QT_NO_EMIT`  - в *.pro файле. Это может иметь побочный эффект, если где-то в вашем коде (или в коде 3-й библиотеки), `emit` используется по своему назначению из Qt.

Другое решение: разделить графический интерфейс и вычислительное ядро приложения разложив его по разным *.cpp файлам. Тогда библиотеки Qt и TBB, небудут встречаться в рамках одного cpp.